# Multiple shell commands in Windows

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate a shell command in R and cannot figure out how to string commands together.  This just returns the contents of the working folder (`system()` fails for some reason):

```
> shell("dir")
 Volume info ..
 Directory of E:\Documents\R
 contents are listed..
```

Now lets try and navigate to C drive and run `dir` (without using the obvious `dir C:`)..

```
> shell("cd C:")
C:\
> shell("dir")
 Volume in drive E is GT
 etc..
```

So it seems commands can't be entered separately as the shell doesn't remember the working directory. So..

```
> (cmd = "cd C:
+ dir")
[1] "cd C:\ndir"
> shell(cmd)
C:\
```

No luck as the C: folders are not reported. Other methods I've tried also fail. Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: As Konrad noted, there are better ways to get the job done in `R`. For example, use `R`'s `dir` function with the pathname specified.  `dir(path='E:/documents/r', pattern='whatever...')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on Linux and this works for me:

```
system("cd ..;ls")
```

in navigating to the previous directory and running ls/dir there. In your case, on Windows, this apparently works:

```
shell("cd C: & dir")
```

or to get the output as a character vector:

`shell("cd C: & dir", intern=T)` and on Linux: `system("cd ..; ls", intern=T)`

Comment: Works thanks! `shell("cd C: & dir", intern=T)` to return char vector

Comment: The documentation specifically says that this doesn’t work on Windows.

Comment: Yes use shell instead of system

Comment: `shell("cd C: & dir")` still lists the contents of R's working directory for me, on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) explains why `system` doesn’t work: it executes the command directly on Windows, without spawning a shell first.

`shell` (or better, `system2`) is the way to go but as you’ve noticed, `shell` will always spawn a *new* shell so that changes to the environment don’t carry over. `system2` won’t work directly either since it quotes its commands (and thus doesn’t allow chaining of commands).

The **correct** solution in this context is not to use a shell command to change the directory. Use `setwd` instead:

```
setwd('C:')
system2('dir')
```

If you want to reset the working directory after executing the command, use the following:

```
local({
    oldwd = getwd()
    on.exit(setwd(oldwd))
    setwd('C:')
    system2('dir')
})
```

Comment: Noted, setwd is better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps, but collapsing the commands to one string when using `system` works on MacOS

```
cmds <- c("ls", "cd ..", "ls");
system(paste(cmds, collapse=";"))
```

Comment: The documentation specifically says that this doesn’t work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution from [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-run-system-command-tp4449597p4451130.html). That solved my problem in calling the windows `dir` command:

```
system("cmd.exe /c dir", intern=TRUE)
```